# Are there any Mantras to bring rain?

Tags: scripture, mantras

We are suffering from water problem without rain. Any suggestions about rain generating Mantras are welcomed. This question may appear as a primarily-opinion based, but actually it is not. So, please don't close it.

Comment: No, mantras do not bring rain. See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18137/2995) and also [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16022/2995).

Comment: @sv. Mantras do bring rain and even now. We have many examples.

Comment: @Rickross I discuss one such 'example' in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18137/2995). The other failed examples are not usually reported. The only way I know that can increase the chance of rains is thru [cloud seeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_seeding#India) but even that doesn't work always. Ever wondered why the Indian states also finally resorted to cloud seeding instead of conducting more Varuna yajñas?

Comment: @sv. if it fails in one case, it doesn't mean mantras can't bring rain. If you write a code and if it doesn't even compile, the problem is not with that language but problem is with you  (programmer). Similarly, if a pundit couldn't bring rains through mantras, we shouldn't blame Mantras. There are  many things which we have to consider.

Comment: @sv Inspired by ur comment i wrote an answer up.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Since you took the example of s/w programming, there's always new programming languages like [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language)#History) coming up to solve the inherent problems with old and archaic languages. So it's not always the programmer's fault :P "if a pundit couldn't bring rains through mantras, we shouldn't blame Mantras" - if Pundit 1 is not uttering the mantras correctly you replace him with a better Pundit. At what point do you give up chanting mantras and try cloud seeding?

Comment: @sv. I was not talking about efficiency of programming languages in above example. For example, if you miss semicolon in Java, code won't compile. In that case you should blame programmer not Java language. Similarly,  i was saying some pundits are not able to efficiently chant some mantras to make them work.

Comment: @sv. Watch this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2KWaNdeYj8

Comment: @TheDestroyer "Correlation does not imply causation" - please repeat this mantra :)

Comment: Whatever mantras available in literature, should be uttered by a person of Rishi calibre.   Otherwise those mantras will remain ineffective.  According to literature, Saints like Sri Shiridi Sai ,  Sri Raghavendra,  etc commanded the nature for getting rains.  So ultimately it boils down to the issue of sankalpa -determination of the saint that matters.@user9554

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rishis of vedic  times stressed on treating nature and one’s environment with total reverence worthy of worship. So they created hymns in honor of every element of nature. Thus we can find prayers /Mantras for rain in different Hindu scriptures like Vedas and Upanishads.

Here  are some of the verses from Fifth Mandala of  [**Rig-Veda**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv05083.htm) which prays for the rain.Here are [**Sanskrit verses**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv05083.htm)

> अछा वद तवसं गीर्भिर आभि सतुहि **पर्जन्यं नमसा** विवास | 
> कनिक्रदद वर्षभो जीरदानू रेतो दधात्य ओषधीषु गर्भम || 5.83.1||
>
> achā vada tavasaṃ ghīrbhir ābhi stuhi **parjanyaṃ namasā** vivāsa |
>
> kanikradad vṛṣabho jīradānū reto dadhāty oṣadhīṣu gharbham ||
>
> SING with these songs thy welcome to the Mighty, with adoration
> **praise and   call Parjanya.** The Bull, loud roaring, swift to send his bounty, lays in the plants  the seed. for germination.
>
> ---
>
> दिवो नो वर्ष्टिम मरुतो ररीध्वम पर पिन्वत वर्ष्णो अश्वस्य धाराः | 
> अर्वाङ एतेन सतनयित्नुनेह्य अपो निषिञ्चन्न असुरः पिता नः || 5.83.6||
>
> अभि करन्द सतनय गर्भम आ धा उदन्वता परि दीया रथेन | 
> दर्तिं सु कर्ष विषितं नयञ्चं समा भवन्तूद्वतो निपादाः || 5.83.7||
>
> महान्तं कोशम उद अचा नि षिञ्च सयन्दन्तां कुल्या विषिताः पुरस्तात | 
> घर्तेन दयावाप्र्थिवी वय उन्धि सुप्रपाणम भवत्व अघ्न्याभ्यः || 5.83.8||
>
> यत पर्जन्य कनिक्रदत सतनयन हंसि दुष्क्र्तः |
> परतीदं विश्वम मोदते यत किं च पर्थिव्याम अधि || 5.83.9||
>
> divo no vṛṣṭim maruto rarīdhvam pra pinvata vṛṣṇo aśvasya dhārāḥ |
>
> arvāṅ etena stanayitnunehy apo niṣiñcann asuraḥ pitā naḥ ||
>
> abhi kranda stanaya gharbham ā dhā udanvatā pari dīyā rathena |
>
> dṛtiṃ su karṣa viṣitaṃ nyañcaṃ samā bhavantūdvato nipādāḥ ||
>
> mahāntaṃ kośam ud acā ni ṣiñca syandantāṃ kulyā viṣitāḥ purastāt |
>
> ghṛtena dyāvāpṛthivī vy undhi suprapāṇam bhavatv aghnyābhyaḥ ||
>
> yat parjanya kanikradat stanayan haṃsi duṣkṛtaḥ |
>
> pratīdaṃ viśvam modate yat kiṃ ca pṛthivyām adhi ||
>
> **6** : **Send down for us the rain of heaven, ye Maruts,** and let the Stallion's flood descend in torrents. Come hither with this
> thunder while thou pourest the waters down, our heavenly Lord and
> Father.
>
> **7** : Thunder and roar: the germ of life deposit. Fly round us on thy chariot water laden. Thine opened water-skin draw with thee
> downward, and let the hollows and the heights be level.
>
> **8**: **Lift up the mighty vessel, pour down water**, and let the liberated streams rush forward.
>
> **9**: When thou, with thunder and with roar, Parjanya, smitest sinners down, This universe exults thereat, yea, all that is upon the
> earth.
>
> ---
>
> अद॑र्द॒रुत्स॒मसृ॑जॊ॒ वि खानि॒ त्वम॑र्ण॒वान्ब॑द्बधा॒नाँ अ॑रम्णाः ।
> म॒हान्त॑मिन्द्र॒ पर्व॑तं॒ वि यद्वः सृ॒जॊ वि धारा॒ अव॑ दान॒वं ह॑न् ॥
> [**5.32.1**](https://shaivam.org/daily-prayers-hindu-prayer-hub/vedic-prayer-for-rain-and-wisdom) ||
>
> adardarutsamasRujO vi khAni tvamarNavAnbadbadhAnA~M aramNAH |
> mahAntamindra parvataM vi yadvaH sRujO vi dhArA ava dAnavaM han ||
> 5.32.1 ||
>
> Breaking open the cloud You create the channels (for rain)! You strike
> fast the mammoth cloud! **Oh Indra! You cast open the mountain of
> cloud making the showers, destroying the darkness!**
>
> ---

Here  is an excerpt from the [**Chandogya Upanishad**](https://archive.org/details/Shankara.Bhashya-Chandogya.Upanishad-Ganganath.Jha.1942.English)   in which an insight is offered detailing a more scientific and logical approach to the importance of rain.

> आपो वावान्नाद्भूयस्तस्माद्यदा सुवृष्टिर्न भवति व्याधीयन्ते प्राणा
> अन्नं कनीयो भविष्यतीत्यथ यदा
>  सुवृष्टिर्भवत्यानन्दिनः प्राणा
> भवन्त्यन्नं बहु भविष्यतीत्याप एवेमा मूर्ता येयं पृथिवी यदन्तरिक्षं
> यद्द्यौर्यत्पर्वता यद्देवमनुष्यायत्पशवश्च वयासि च तृणवनस्पतयः
> श्वापदान्याकीटपतङ्गपिपीलकमाप
>  एवेमा मूर्ता अप उपास्स्वेति ॥ ७.१०.१॥
>
> Apo vāvānnād bhūyasyaḥ | tasmād yadā suvṛṣṭir na bhavati vyādhīyante
> prāṇā annaṃ kanīyo `evemā |mūrtā yeyaṃ pṛthivī yad antarikṣaṃ yad
> dyaur yat parvatā yad devamanuṣyā yat paśavaś ca vayāṃsi ca
> tṛṇavanaspatayaḥ śvāpadāny ākīṭapataṅgapipīlakam | āpa evemā mūrtāḥ |
> apa upāssveti |
>
> “Water is greater than food. **Therefore, if there is not sufficient
> rain, living beings fail from fear that there will be less food. But
> if there is sufficient rain, they become happy because there will be
> much food.** This water, by assuming different forms, becomes this
> earth, sky, heaven, mountains, gods and men, cattle, birds, herbs and
> trees, all beasts down to worms, midges, and ants. Water itself
> assumes all these forms. Meditate on water”.

Answer (score 5):

The Veda mantras to bring rain are also to be found in the Atharva Veda (AV).

The Suktas, AV 4.15 and AV 7.18, are entirely dedicated to rain.

> Samikshayantu tavishA prudAnvo (1) ApAm rasA oshadhimihi sachantAm (2)
>   Varshasya sargo mahayantu bhumim (3) Prithag jAyantAm oshadhayo
>   viswrupAh (4)
>
> ....
>
> By the grace of mighty ones and auspicious donors (1), let the essence
>   (rasa) in the waters come to the herbs (2). Let the gushes of rain
>   gladden the earth (3); Let all forms of (medicinal) plants be born
>   here and there.
>
> **AV 4.15.2**

In these Suktas, the Marut Gods, who are the helpers of Indra, are asked to propel the clouds to yield rain.

Some further mantras are as follows:

> Apo viddhut abhram varpa sam vo avantu sudhAnava (1) UtsA ajagarA uta
>   (2)
>
> .....
>
> Let the waters, lightning, cloud, rain favour lavish givers (1), also
>   favour the fountains and serpents (ajagarA).
>
> **AV 4.15.9**

....

> Pra navasva prithivi bhindri idam divyam navah (1) Udro divyasya no
>   dhAtarishAno vishvA datim (2)
>
> ..........
>
> Earth is asked to split the cloud of heaven. (1) and release the water
>   in the bag.
>
> **AV 7.18.2**

Yet another mantra (only translation given) is:

> Open and raise up (udacha) the great covering sheath and spribkle
>   abundantly along with the lightning and wind. Let thew sacrifice be
>   extended (tanvata) and released in amny ways. Let the growths of earth
>   (oshadhayah) become full of delight.
>
> **AV 4.15.16**

Also, we should not doubt the fact that Yajnas (if properly done) can bring rains. As the scriptures clearly say that it can:

> Manu Smriti 3.76. **An oblation duly thrown into the fire, reaches the
>   sun; from the sun comes rain**, from rain food, therefrom the living
>   creatures (derive their subsistence).

In Veda mantras, God Indra has been appealed to release rain in times of draught and to stop downpour in times of excessive rainfall.

Even, in these times, there have been persons who have displayed those powers at times of real need alone.

One such person was [Sri Ganapati Muni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganapati_Muni) (1878-1936), an adept in Vedas and Tantras and the first disciple of Sri Ramana Maharshi.

Now, those who want empirical evidences of experiments comprising of Yajnas bringing out rain in times when it is needed and stopping it when it has been excessive downpour, can read the book **Vedic Metereology by Ravi PrakAsh Arya**.

This book records over 400 such experiments, performed in various parts of India, over a period some 40 years in this century.

Several of these experiments have been successful and they have the following key features:

> (1) Specification of the appropriate atmospheric conditions as
>   relevant to each season; for instance, wind has to blow from a certain
>   direction in a particular season.
>
> (2) Performance of a prticular type of Yajna accompanied by chanting of
>   Veda Mantras.
>
> (3) Spiritual attainment of the person performing the Yjana. Absolute
>   faith in the efficacy of the procedure is essential to its success.
>   There can be no guarantee of the rain pouring down or its stopping,
>   should an unbeleliever follow the procedure casually with meeting its
>   prerequisites.

So, it is not as easy as chanting few mantras or performing few Yajnas and rain will start pouring down, but it is not impossible too.

Comment: "This book records over 400 such experiments" - what is the success rate? 100%? Did any of them fail? If yes, why did they fail? What if all these 'successful' experiments are simply coincidence? (see [Correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation) or [Post hoc fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy#Post_hoc_.28false_cause.29))

Comment: @sv 100 % success rate is impossible to achieve at least in Kali Yuga.. because for the Veda mantras to work so many prerequisites are there..Also there are certain Agamas which even say that Veda mantras are powerless in Kali Yuga..so lots of factors to be considered.. Also, if u happen to live during the period of Ganapati Muni then u could have seen such things happening with ur own eyes..As u know "Pratyaksha Anubhuti" is the greatest of all proofs.

Comment: @sv What if all these 'successful' experiments are simply coincidence? .. Actually for someone like me (or us) no scope of ifs and but..I don't even have the need to give the proofs of how our ancestors have witnessed such things to happen over the ages..We actually have seen such things (rainfall after long dry days) happening in our first Guruji's Ashrama after prolonged Yajnas..we have seen Gods coming into the fire..the pics taken of the havan fire even clearly show the flute of Krishna or the lion of Goddess Chandika

Comment: @sv.We have seen how the havan fire is continuously burning inspite of continuous heavy rains..so we know that these things are true and can even be empirically verified.. But i seriously don't know how to convince a non believer.. Actually they need to engage themselves if they are genuine in their quests.. Having prejudices won't help.

Comment: Does Ravi Prakash Arya follow Arya Samaj?

Comment: Not sure have to check @NarayanaSharma

Comment: He is having Arya surname. So a small doubt...

Comment: I don't think having that surname implies that one is from that ORg but will check, probably not. @NarayanaSharma

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are many mantras in the Vedas which are for rains. In fact yajnas are primarily performed for the well being of all the living creatures. Through the smoke of the yajnas the clouds are invoked and attracted to bring rain. Rain helps the flora and fauna thus creating the necessary balance in the ecosystem.

> All living bodies subsist on food grains, which are produced from
>   rain. Rains are produced by performance of yajna [sacrifice], and
>   yajna is born of prescribed duties.

(Geeta 3.14)

There are several [instances](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/Rekindling-a-vedic-fire-ritual/articleshow/7352633.cms) when rain has came on the last day of grand yajnas like agnistoma.

Varuna yaagam is frequently held at the famous Tirumala Tirupati temple. It has brought good rains many times.

[This year](http://www.deccanchronicle.com/nation/current-affairs/300517/varuna-japa-yagam-begins-in-tirumala.html) also Varuna yaga was conducted there.

> Yajur Veda mentions that the waters with which Varuna is connected are the waters of the atmosphere. These waters are described
>   as Apah, Maha-salilam the great waters which denote primeval matter
>   from which the manifest world emerges. Aditi the great mother of all
>   gods is also said to give birth to the manifest world. Aditi is thus
>   equated with Apah. As Apah, Aditi is the creative energy which is
>   active (YV.10.7).That is, Aditi the mother of all gods is Prakrti and
>   Shakthi the manifesting or the creative power. The notion of her
>   divinity rests upon her power as a woman, a womb or a mother to give
>   birth to and to bring forth life and existence.
>
> Varuna (son of Aditi) who resides among these waters (Apah) is
>   therefore called the child of the waters (Apam shishu) in the best of
>   mothers. It is explained; the expression ‘best of mothers’ refers to
>   the protective and nourishing nature of the waters as mothers. They
>   are the gracious guides and protective mothers; and, Varuna is their
>   child.
>
> [It is also said; since Varuna dwells in waters he was also called
>   Apam Napat (Apam = water; Napat = fire), ‘Son of the Waters’
>   (RV.1.2.35). Apam Napat is also referred to as the embryo (garbha) of
>   the waters (RV.7.9.3). It is said; the sun when he sinks into waters –
>   to quench his thirst – becomes Varuna the fire in the waters (Apam
>   Napat).
>
> In the Yajna
>
> Yajur Veda is the book of Yajnas. During an Yajna,   Varuna along with
>   Mitra is invoked and invited to take seat on the North side of the
>   altar Yajna-vedi and requested to protect Rta the law of nature ; and
>   also to bring good rains (YV. 2.3; 2.16). The invitation to Varuna to
>   occupy the seat on the North is interesting. North is the direction of
>   the gods; it is the direction of Soma initially (as per Brih.
>   Upanishad) and then of Kubera the sub-divine who is friendly with
>   gods. Thus, in Yajur Veda, Varuna was still the major god of the
>   Yajna. In the later texts Varuna was, however, assigned a seat on the
>   West where the sun sinks into sea and into the night.
>
> The hymns in Atharva Veda in praise of Varuna ‘the most impressive
>   deity among all the Vedic gods’ are lofty, more devout and ethical in
>   tone. They pray for purity, forgiveness, and release from sins, and
>   for moral strength against sinning further.   The hymns rise to a
>   pitch of exaltation as they sing the splendour of Varuna. In these
>   hymns Varuna, more than any other Vedic god, appears as a mighty and
>   merciful.
>
> Of the many soulful hymns submitted to Varuna,  the sixteenth hymn in
>   the fourth book of the Atharva Veda  sung by sage Vashista celebrating
>   Varuna’s power and omniscience is often quoted and hailed by scholars
>   as being among the most devote and forceful hymns in the Vedic
>   literature
>
> While mentioning his connection with waters Varuna is referred to as–
>   Apam-adhipathi the Lord who resides in the primeval waters. These
>   waters are described as of golden hue, pure and purifying; and, they
>   are the material cause for creation (AV.1.33.1-3)
>
> The Brahmanas, especially the Shatapatha Brahmana (SB) carry elaborate
>   discussions about the relationship that exists between truth (Sathya)
>   and waters. It said; truth is the same as waters for waters are the
>   truth. Hence: ’whereby waters flow that is the form of truth. It is
>   the waters indeed that were first made in the universe. When waters
>   flow everything whatever that exists is produced.”(SB.10.5.4.1).
>   Waters also symbolize the law. Water causes everything to exist and to
>   grow in order. The waters are the reality (SB.7.6.1.4) and represent
>   immortality (Amrtatavam va Apah – SB.1.9.3.7). They are the faith
>   (Shraddaha) in life (Tai.Br.3.2.4.1). All gods and all beings are
>   water; as they are the foundation and the ultimate source of the
>   universe; and everything is contained in them (SB 10.5.4.4.15).
>
> Varuna in Aranyakas
>
> Varuna is briefly discussed in the Aitareya Aranyaka at two places;
>   and both refer to Varuna’s mystical association with waters. There are
>   no allusions to his Vedic glory as the sky-god, or as the king or as
>   the governor of the laws.
>
> The waters referred to in these passages are philosophical suggestions
>   as they denote the primeval waters or the primeval matter. Here, the
>   creation of waters and of Varuna comes about as an expression of the
>   Supreme Being’s will or desire. It is metaphorically said that they
>   were born out of the manas the mind of the Supreme Being. Varuna is
>   the mythical symbol of primeval matter. Thus, philosophically, waters
>   and Varuna stand for Prakrti or the Becoming. It is the first stage of
>   manifest world.

[Source](https://sreenivasaraos.com/tag/varuna-in-atharva-veda/)

Comment: Yes. Yaga definitely bring rain. When we performed Yaga, on that evening rain came. But here the question is not about whether Yaga bring rain or not, but some Mantras to bring rain

Comment: "Through the smoke of the yajnas the clouds are invoked and attracted to bring rain." - this is a falsifiable statement and can be easily refuted by conducting a yajña and waiting for the result. If there's no gathering of clouds and therefore no rain, the yajña simply didn't yield the desired results.

Comment: @sv. yes but there are many instances where rain has come during the time of purnahuti of such yagas., i think where were those videos too on youtube.

Comment: @Ajay technically if u want to pray you can use normal mantras too. if you want specific then varuna mantra and varuna suktam

Answer (score 1):

**Rishya Srunga Sloka**

This was recommended by Shankaracharya of Kanchi to bring rainfall.

**Sloka in English**

> Rishyasringaaya munaye vibhandaka sutaayaca
>
> Namah saantadhipataye satyah sadvrishti hetave
>
> Vibhandaka sutah sreemaan saantaadhipathir akalmashaha
>
> Rishyasringa itignyaataha mahaa varsham prayachathu

Answer (score 1):

Parjanya Sukta was mentioned in [Rig Veda V.83](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv05083.htm).  As mantras in Rig Veda contains multi-layered meaning, It can be interpreted spiritually and literally. It is for rain God.

However, readers should bear in mind that utterance of these mantras not only ***require proper knowledge of method of recitation, but also austerity power of the invoker.***

For example, [Kanakadhara stotram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanakadh%C4%81ra_Stotram) was composed by Sri Sankara.  It was told that as per the wish of Sri Sankara,  a poor lady's house was with goose berries made of ***pure gold***.

Then onwards many pundits/scholars might have recited **Kanakadhara stotram**, umpteen number of times in temples or in houses.  How many of them got the golden goose berries in the respective places?

The proper recitation of any mantra should be backed up with austerity power, as proved in Sri Sankara's case, of the reciter.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Vedic mantras that cannot be chanted by everyone, the Rishyashringa Shlokam is one that can be chanted by all. It does bring rain, as I have witnessed personally. Jagadguru Pujyashree Shankara Vijayendra Sarasvati Shankaracharya Svami had a hall full of people chant it one hot May Day and it poured after an hour or two.

Rishyasringaaya munayay Vibhandaka sutaayacha (Rishyashringa muni, son of Vibhandaka)

Namah Shantadhipataye Sadyaha Sadvrishti haytavay (Husband of Shanta, help by bringing rain immediately)

Vibhandaka Sutah Shreemaan Shantaadhipathir Akalmashaha (Blemishless son of Vibhandaka and husband of Shanta)

Rishyasringa Iti Khyaataha Mahaa Varsham Prayachathu (Remowned Rishyashringa, please send heavy rain)

The story of how Rishyashringa brought rain to the Anga kingdom of Raja Romapāda is retold in Valmiki's Rāmāyanam--Bālakanda.

Answer (score 0):

Kṛṣṇa gave us the solution in *[Bhagavad-gītā 3.14](http://causelessmercy.com/?P=Bg3#1)*:

> *annād bhavanti bhūtāni*
>
> *parjanyād anna-sambhavaḥ*
>
> *yajñād bhavati parjanyo*
>
> *yajñaḥ karma-samudbhavaḥ*
>
> **TRANSLATION**
>
> **All living bodies subsist on food grains, which are produced from
>   rain. Rains are produced by performance of *yajña* [sacrifice], and
>   *yajña* is born of prescribed duties.**

The purport says: "Yajña, specifically the *saṅkīrtana-yajña* prescribed for this age, must therefore be performed to save us at least from scarcity of food supply." So we must do *yajña*.

I have seen and also participating in *yajñas* while living in India. Every single night there was rainfall and nice sunshine during the day. All kinds of growing crops could be seen everywhere. People performed sacrifices every day and living a decent life.

One evening I was staying in a temple, participating in kirtan. After 2 hours, a big rainfall came down. There is also a verse from the Palashruti section in Vishnusahasranama.

> *vedāntagō brāhmaṇaḥ syāt kṣatriyō vijayī bhavet* |
>
> *vaiśyō dhanasamṛddhaḥ syāt śūdrassukhamavāpnuyāt* || 3 ||
>
> The Brahmin will get knowledge,
>
> The kshatriya will get victory,
>
> The vaisya will get wealth,
>
> The shudra will get pleasures,
>
> By reading these.

How can all of these four--*brahnim, ksatriya, vaisya* and *shurda*--be happy without having a substantial amount of food supplies? So I recommend chanting Vishnusahasranama ([PDF](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/vishnu/Sri_Vishnu.pdf)) to solve your economic problems. That's my advice.