# Prasada Mantra?? Pranav Mantra?

Tags: mantras

help me understand this answer.. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17586/19305

om padmni om

om nama sivaya

svacchanda bhairavaya namah

These sentences are collections of sacred words. **Collections of sacred words are not mantras, but just a waste of time for the aspirant.** In a real sense, these two - the aspirant's mind and a sacred word experienced as prasada mantra and/or pranav amantra - are mantras.

Prasada Mantra?? Pranav Mantra??

Comment: The definitions of **Prasada Mantra** and **Pranav Mantra** are already explained in the answer referred to, as follows. **Prasada mantra is "the mantra of external flow."Pranava mantrais "the mantra of external and internal flow." It is the internal flow in the external world and the external flow in the internal world**.  Please check

Comment: However, those explanations have deep meanings, which need elaborate explanation @HinduKid

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Collections of sacred words are not mantras, but just a waste of time for the aspirant. ... Only Pranav Mantra effective or something..

Comment: You can go through this answer for understanding the issue to some extent (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36381/3869)

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Understood.