# Why is the Virata Parva of the Mahabharata is read during the srAddha ceremony?

Tags: practice, culture, sraddha

In Bengal, I heard that the  Virata Parva of the Mahabharata is read aloud during the srAddha ceremony.

I am not aware of whether this is followed in other parts of India though.

What is the scriptural reason of reading this on this ceremony?

Comment: Most likely folklore just as [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16006).

Comment: Most likely kula & desha achara, which is corruptly translated as 'folklore' in english language.